# How to access images and background colours in RecyclerView - onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, colors, background

I'm trying to access my background colours and images for onBindViewHolder method.
Images are in res.mipmap folder after I created new Image assets.
Colours are in res.values.colours.xml file

Thanks in advance for help.

for exact code see image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Gq4.jpg

Comment: can you, please, describe a little bit more what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access resources, you can use view's context.

```
holder.view.resources.getColor(id)
holder.view.resources.getDrawable(id)
```